# Get the row that contains most words of a string in a field

Tags: mysql

In PHP I have a string `$str = 'word1 word2 word3'`.

Then I have a mysql-db-field called `content`.

Which MySQL-statement do I need to get the row that has **most** words of `str` in its `content`?

Example:

- Field of Row1: word1 word2 word1 word1 word2
- Field of Row2: word9 word2 word1 word8 word2
- Field of Row3: word1 word2 word1 word1 word3

Would output `Row3`, as it contains `word1`, `word2` and `word3`.

- Field of Row1: word1 word2 word1 word1 word2
- Field of Row2: word9 word2 word2 word8 word2
- Field of Row3: word1 word1 word1 word1 word9

Would output `Row1`, as it contains `word1` and `word2`.

Comment: What did you try yourself to solve this question?  (I think it cannot be done in 1 MySQL-statement)

Comment: Full text indexes? Is this for something like tag clouds?

Comment: Terminology tip: It's not a MySQL "command", it's typically called a "statement".

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with PHP or mysqli? Why do you insist on tagging it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (if you have MySQL8.0 or newer) do:

```
SET @str = 'word1 word2 word3';

DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS content;
CREATE TABLE content(i integer, str VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO content VALUES
    (1,'word1 word2 word1 word1 word2'),
    (2,'word9 word2 word1 word8 word2'),
    (3,'word1 word2 word1 word1 word3');

WITH RECURSIVE abc AS (
   SELECT 
      LEFT(@str,instr(@str,' ')-1) as a, 
      MID(CONCAT(@str,' '),instr(@str,' ')+1) as b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT LEFT(b,instr(b,' ')-1), MID(b,instr(b,' ')+1)
   FROM abc
   WHERE rtrim(b)<>'')
SELECT
  x.i,
  content.str,
  sum(c)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a , 
    content.str, 
    content.i,
    (length(content.str)-length(replace(content.str,a,'')))/length(a) as c
  FROM abc
  CROSS JOIN content) x
INNER JOIN content on content.i=x.i
GROUP BY x.i;
```

output:

| i | str | sum(c) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | word1 word2 word1 word1 word2 | 5.0000 |
| 2 | word9 word2 word1 word8 word2 | 3.0000 |
| 3 | word1 word2 word1 word1 word3 | 5.0000 |

The `WITH RECURSIVE` part create a temporary table abc with a many records as words in `@str`.

After that it is just some work to count the occurrences.